# Question tags after half proverbs

Tags: proverbs

According to Longman, there are some proverbs *(my examples below)* that native speakers mostly use half of. In this case, I was wondering weather it would sound natural, if I use a question tag after a half proverb for the sake of emphasis, or it's not a common practice?

I'm asking this, because a proverb is so often used in the society that works like a crystal clear fact, and technically a question tag seems redundant.

For example:

> Well, **the grass is always greener**, isn't it?

or

> **It's the last straw,** isn't it? / wasn't it?

Comment: It sounds perfectly normal and idiomatic.  Is this not possible in your native language?

Comment: 1) Please edit your question to tell more about how or why you're concerned that it might not be natural; you'll get better answers that way. 2) Why only half a proverb? I don't see that it changes anything if the full proverb is present (unless it's a proverb with multiple sentences or complex clauses). "The grass is always greener on the other side of the fence, isn't it?" (But "Fool me once, shame on you; fool me twice, shame on me" is enough to confuse some presidents, let alone incorporate into a larger sentence.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it sounds perfectly idiomatic, and it is commonly used.